# Thymeleaf StringTemplateResolver with flux doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

My configuration is here

```
@Configuration
class TemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun templateResolver(): StringTemplateResolver? {
        val templateResolver = StringTemplateResolver()
        templateResolver.templateMode = TemplateMode.TEXT

        return templateResolver
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun templateEngine(): SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine {
        var engine = SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine()
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver())
        return engine
    }
}
```

and

```kotlin
var books = Flux.fromArray(arrayOf(Book( ....), Book(....))
var context = Context()

var streamData = ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(books, 10)
context.setVariable("books", streamData)

// then something like below
engine.process(template, context)
```

Error message is: 
org.thymeleaf.templateparser.text.TextParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "book.price" (template: "[# th:each="book: ${books}"] - [(${book.price})] [/]"
......
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'price' cannot be found on object of type 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webflux.ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable' - maybe not public or not valid?
......

I think it's a problem that the Flux Stream was not delivered properly.
How can i solve this?

Plz help me and I apologize in advance for the poor of my English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a solution (maybe is a workaround??)

I use collectList().map instead of ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable
then it worked

```
var books = Flux.fromArray(arrayOf(Book( ....), Book(....))
var context = Context()

books.collectList()
     .map { list ->

            context.setVariable("books", list)
            engine.process(template, context)
      }
```

It's a some kind of monologue ^^;;;

Comment: That sounds like a workaround, but I still wonder why `ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable` was not working. I'm getting the same sort of error you are. Did you discover the problem?